# Mysql set different UUID for different row in multi row insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to generate different uuid for each row, during multiple insert.

First I created a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE uuid_test(
    `id`       INTEGER      INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `col1`     VARCHAR(20)  DEFAULT '',
    `uuid_col` VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '',
    `col2`     INTEGER      DEFAULT 0,
    `col3`     BIT(1) DEFAULT 1,
    UNIQUE (`col1`, `uuid_col`, `col2`)
)ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then I tried of adding a trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON uuid_test
FOR EACH  ROW  
BEGIN
    SET NEW.uuid_col := UUID() ;
END
$$
```

Then I tried to insert two column using isert select

```
INSERT INTO kudos_voting(col1, col2) select col1, col2 from table2;
```

The result:

```
mysql> select * from uuid_test;
+----+------------+--------------------------------------+------------+-------+
| id | col1       | uuid_col                             | col2       | col3  |
+----+------------+--------------------------------------+------------+-------+
|  3 | gjsfgjks   | 3205a742-961f-11e5-be40-086266261210 |          4 |     1 |
|  4 | gjsfgjks   | 3206ccaf-961f-11e5-be40-086266261210 |          4 |     1 |
+----+------------+--------------------------------------+------------+-------+
```

Here I am facing two doubts.

1. Why the same uuid is inserted everytime
2. Though I have added  UNIQUE
   (`col1`, `uuid_col`, `col2`), then why its not throwing any error
   during insertion of the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, be more careful: the uuids are different (3205a742 vs 3206ccaf - compare the first parts). So everything works like you suggested and there shouldn't be any errors.

Comment: Sorry I have not clearly marked. Thank youvery much.